# Find usages of a function in entire solution MVS 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-assist, visual-assist-x

I use Visual Studio 2008 with Visual Assist X for codding on C++. And I want to find a function usages - all the lines in the solution where the function call was invoked (Please note that I don't want to find the lines, where there is a call of a function with the SAME NAME, but I want to find the places where EXACTLY that function was called.) How can I do this?

Comment: Is modifying code for diagnostic purpose an acceptable solution for you?

Comment: You could do some hackery in code collect the information you need and revert back to the original code.Would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Change the function (its name, maybe), get a bunch of compilation errors, change it back.

Comment: Oh no! :) There is no a civil way of doing that???

Comment: Does VAssistX | Find References give incorrect results?

Comment: It does not give only usages. It gives references to that **word** in general